# Pull a single file from a git repository

Tags: git, latex

I am writing a thesis in (Xe)LaTeX and versioning it on remote git repo X.
The template I use is maintained by another person on remote git repo Y.

I need to add one template file template.sty from Y in my repository.
And when template.sty changes in Y, I should be able to change it in X also with one or two commands.

So that, I can use -

`git pull origin` to pull my repository X

`git pull template_repo` [?] to get updated version of the template.sty from Y

I have found a couple of answers here using `git archive` which won't fit my need. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is pull a single file from a branch. Where that branch is hosted should not make a difference because you can only check out from remote branches after fetching.

```
git fetch template_repo branch_name #probably master
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- path/to/your/file
```

I see that you are trying to pull. Pull does a fetch and then a merge (or rebase, if specified) into the current branch. This will not work for single files. In general it is easier to fetch and then merge so that you can see what you are merging before you do so; with pull it always done blindly.